# Polymorphic association in JPA

Tags: jpa

I like to have a single table ADDRESS in the Database and multiple unrelated entities for example User, Office will have one to many relations with the Address entity. In a nutshell my Entities would looke like

```
@Entity 
public class Address {

@Id 
private long id;

@Column 
private String entityType; // served as discriminator e-g User,Office ...

@Column 
private long entityId; // served as foreign key

... other address columns    
}
```

User Class

```
public class User {

@Id 
private long id;

@OneToMany
private List<Adress> addresses;t

}
```

Office class

```
@Entity
public class Office {
   @Id 
    private long id;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<Adress> addresses;
    
}
```

I tried @Any of Hibernate but that's not helping with One-to-Many relations. It has either Many-to-One and Many-to-Many relationships. What is the best way to achieve this in JPA.

Comment: Usually, the way to go is to make your address an `@Embeddable` but it depends on the use case. If yours justifies the addresses to have their own identity I can understand, but can you tell us what your database table looks like? Because a foreign key can only go to a single other table

Comment: `@Embeddable` will make the address table relation as one to one, but in our case, a person can have multiple addresses, e-g MAILING_ADDRESS, BILLING_ADDRESS etc.

the adress table will have primarykey=id, foreign key= entityType,entityId, a string field to identify ADDRESS_TYPE and so on

Comment: That's correct indeed

Comment: It seems what you are trying to do is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984300/im-trying-to-make-two-different-table-manytoone-mapping-in-single-column-for-on/66989871?noredirect=1#comment118423437_66989871