# i'm trying to make two different table manytoone mapping in single column for one entity class

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

i'm new to hibernate two manytoone mapping column make to single column

my entity class

```
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="assignedto_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)   
      private User assignedto;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="assignedto_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
      private LDAPUser assignedto1;
```

mysql table column

```
  KEY `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` (`assignedto_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` FOREIGN KEY (`assignedto_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_master_user` (`ID`)
```

i want mysql table column like this

```
 KEY `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` (`assignedto_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` FOREIGN KEY (`assignedto_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_master_user` (`ID`)

 KEY `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` (`assignedto_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FKs437l1xgobeh3iucqmifj356i` FOREIGN KEY (`assignedto_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_ldap_master` (`ID`)
```

please help me thank you in advance

Comment: See the hibernate orm documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-any

Comment: i didn't understand anything

Comment: How does `User` relates to `LDAPUser`, if one extends the other you can use inheritance mapping. Can you show the classes?

Comment: user and ldapuser are completely different class but i want to store both user in single column. is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is explained in the [Hibernate ORM section about `@Any` annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-any):

```
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "userType"))
@AnyMetaDef(name = "PropertyMetaDef", metaType = "string", idType = "long",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(value = "User", targetEntity = User.class),
                    @MetaValue(value = "LDAP", targetEntity = LDAPUser.class)
            }
    )
@JoinColumn(name="assignedto_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)   
private Object assignedTo
```

But it won't create any foreign keys.
I don't even think is possible to create two foreign keys on the same column for different tables (does it even make sense?).

Alternatively, if the two classes could extend from a common super class, you could use [Inheritance mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table) to achieve something similar.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public static class UserEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class User extends UserEntity {
...
}

@Entity
public class LDAPUser extends UserEntity {
...
}
```

and then

```
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="assignedto_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)   
      private UserEntity assignedto;
```

This will create three tables though. The table `UserEntity` will have a foreign key on the `assignedto_id` column. `User` id and `LDAPUser` id will have a constraint each on `UserEntity` id. Basically, getting close to what you asked originally.

Comment: it's working for both classes but when i'm going to update User id or LDAPuser id i can't do that because we are not applying getter and setter for 2 classes separately

Comment: how can i get that id which class id i want because i need to check condition for both class. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need to do. But it should be possible with this mapping. Plus, I'm not sure why you are trying to update the id.

Comment: If you need to check some conditions on both entities, you can create a method in the super class for doing that.

Comment: I think my answer cover your first question though, Would you accept it as the correct one, please?